# [Unity 5]Every color in the scene appears to be "burned". Randomly increased alpha in every color

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

I am having a very weird issue that appeared literally out of nowhere.
I absolutely did not meddle with anything, I was simply in play mode (without having touched any code or Unity settings) and upon stopping, and ever since, all colors appear to be burned, sort of like having their alpha value increased a lot. This applies to everything in every scene.

The only workaround I have found is disabling the Post Processing Profile's Color Grading option on my Main Camera, which I obviously don't want to, but it's the only way to "unburn" the colors.

You can see the relative screenshots below.

Does anyone have any idea what might have randomly caused this issue? I am using Unity version 2017.2.0f3

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As randomly as the bug occurred, so I found the solution.
What I did was disable HDR and then quit out of Unity. I then rebooted it and re enabled HDR and voila, colors aren't burned anymore. I still understand none of it.